# Removing disk quotas in Scientific Linux

Tags: disk-usage, scientific-linux

- Im doing some big data integrations in MongoDB at the moment.
- MongoDB's files are stored at /data/db
- Scientific Linux has automatically setup `root` to have a small amount of disk space and me, `bob` to have a huge amount.

.

```
 [bob@bob etc]$ df -h
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/vg_bob-lv_root
                        50G  5.5G   44G  12% /
 tmpfs                 7.7G  284K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
 /dev/sda1             485M   43M  418M  10% /boot
 /dev/mapper/vg_bob-lv_home
                       1.8T  277M  1.7T   1% /home
 [bob@bob etc]$
```

- For some reason, MongoDB is limited to `root`'s disk quota - even though I've added `bob` to the sudoers and run `sudo service mongod start` as `bob`.
- How can I let this spill over?

Essentially I would like to simply remove all disk quotas and let all users use however much they want.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: The problem is your root partition is too small to hold your DB. If I were you, I'd just put the DB somewhere different, like in your home area: [changing mogodb data storing directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-storing-directory).

Comment: `sudo service mongod start` will run `service` as root, whoever you are when you launch that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use mongo but I would presume there is a way to configure its data directory, in which case your best bet might be to create a directory for it in `/home` and then use that instead of `/data/db`.  You would want to do that as root, so the directory still has the correct owner. *[see the last paragraph here for more about that...]*

Another option is to use a *symbolic (aka 'soft') link*.  First:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/mongo/data/db
```

This creates the directory you are going to use within the 1.8 TB `/home` partition.  Now check what the ownership and permissions are on `/data/db` and make sure they are duplicated for the new directory. Now move all the data from `/data/db` into that directory and delete the now empty inner `db` directory (but not `/data` itself).  Next:

```
sudo ln -s /home/mongo/data/db /data/db
```

This creates a soft link from `/data/db` to `/home/mongo/data/db`; anything put into the former will actually go into the later, and likewise WRT to accessing the content (these two paths are *linked* and point to the same place, which is the one in `/home`).  If you haven't used sym links like this before, they are a pretty handy general purpose *nix tool and very easy to understand.  Google and read up on them.

Some software, generally outward facing servers, may have (optional) security restrictions to do with following symlinks.  I did a quick web search to check about this WRT mongo and I don't think there is a problem, but in the process I did find this comment about the data directory, lol:

> By default, mongod writes data to the /data/db/ directory. [...] You
>   can specify, and create, an alternate path using the --dbpath option
>   to mongod and the above command.

From: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/ So there is another clue about your options ;)

Comment: Thanks for this! I took the even lazier route of deleting /data/db and simply running it as sudo mongod --dbpath /home/mongo & which works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

Run `quota`
If there are active quotas you can run `quotaoff -a` to disable all quota for current session.
To permanetly disable quota edit /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove quota enforcement and maintence for a disk if you add the mount option for it in the /etc/fstab called 'noquota'.